# On cell click the value of a label should increase and decrease

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an Array which I first load into tableview cell, Then on clicking the cell, the value gets appended to an array and it prints the sum of all elements in an array to a UILabel.

This works fine when the array has different elements, but it fails when there are same elements.

Here is my Code.

```
let amount:[String] = ["1","1","1"]
var amountsSelected:[String] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // Check if it is not in the array
    if(!amountsSelected.contains(amount[indexPath.row])){

        amountsSelected.append(amount[indexPath.row])

        let intArray = amountsSelected.map { Int($0)!}

        let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
        moneyText.text = String(total)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }


    }else if(amountsSelected.contains(amount[indexPath.row])){
       //check if it is present in the array
        amountsSelected.append(amount[indexPath.row])

        let intArray = amountsSelected.map { Int($0)!}

        let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
        moneyText.text = String(total)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }


    }else{
       //just remove
        amountsSelected = amountsSelected.filter({$0 != amount[indexPath.row]})
        print(amountsSelected)
        let intArray = amountsSelected.map { Int($0)!}

        let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
        moneyText.text = String(total)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }

}
```

On trying this even after deselecting the value of UILabel keeps increasing instead of decreasing.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Please point out the differences between the if and the else-if clause. Maybe I am missing something but to me they look the same. Also, did you ever manage to get into the last else-clause, seems impossible to me.

Comment: in the first, if I compare if(!amountsSelected.contains(amount[indexPath.row])) //i.e., i check if it is not present in the array .  And in elseif I Do else if(amountsSelected.contains(amount[indexPath.row])) //Check if they are same .And in else I do amountsSelected = amountsSelected.filter({$0 != amount[indexPath.row]}) just removing

Comment: OK, let's sort out some issues: first, the code inside the if and the else-if-clause are the same. So the same thing will happen regardless of the condition. Second, the else-clause cannot be called (as Daniel pointed out). Third, you just posted the didSelect-method, so there is nothing happening on deselecting it (as you seem to be expecting a decrease).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing code, you are adding the value to array only if that array already not containing the same string. so, when you try with the same elements `["1","1","1"]` those are not added multiple times and thus it leads to incorrect results and not behaving as you are expecting.

To fix it, you can define an array `selectedIndexPath` which holds the indexPaths which already selected

```
var selectedIndexPath: [IndexPath] = []
```

Update your `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath.removeAll { (indPath) -> Bool in
            indexPath == indPath
        }
        let selectedValue = amount[indexPath.row]
        let deselectedIndex = amountsSelected.firstIndex(of: selectedValue)
        amountsSelected.remove(at: deselectedIndex!)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexPath.append(indexPath)

        let selectedValue = amount[indexPath.row]
        amountsSelected.append(selectedValue)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    let intArray = amountsSelected.map { Int($0)!}
            let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
            moneyText.text = String(total)
            print(total)
}
```

and modify your `cellForRow` methods to show checkMark if contains the indexPath in array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE dequeueReusableCell
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        //cell?.textLabel?.text = amount[indexPath.row]

        //THIS CHECK NEEDS TO BE ADDED ON CELL FOR ROW AT METHOD
        if selectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell!
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gerriet: one of either your "if" statement or your "else if" statements must be true as they are the opposite of each other. Thus your "else" statement will never fire.

if (not in the array) then do stuff; else
if (in the array) then do the same stuff...

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem, you have to create an Array of **selectedIndexes** and check in didSelect delegate whether that index exist in the array if so then remove it from the **selectedIndexes** array otherwise add it into that arry.

This code will resolve your issue:

```
let amount:[String] = ["1","1","1"]
var selectedIndexes = [Int]()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row)){
        selectedIndexes = selectedIndexes.filter{ $0 != indexPath.row }
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }

    // update total count label here

    let intArray = selectedIndexes.compactMap { Int(amount[$0]) }

    let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
    moneyText.text = String(total)

}
```

Hope it will help you.